# I would like to retrieve words with their number of characters

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Like in the title. I would like to retrieve words with their number of characters with Ruby. I have searched a lot there are a lot of methods to select elements in an array. But is it possible to recover for example only the strings which contain 5 characters in my array?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: _"the strings which contain 5 characters in my array"_ – how does that array look like? Show the corresponding code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, something like this could work

```
words_with_five_characters = words.select { |w| w.length == 5 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already converted your title to an `array` of words, in which case the answer from @Ursus is perfect.

If that's of any help, you can also start from the `string` directly and use [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression to identify 5 letter words:

```rb
title = 'this is my title and it has a lot of words including some longer than five characters'
title.scan(/\b\w{5}\b/)
=> ["title", "words"]
```

Comment: `/\w{5}/` doesn't take word boundaries into account – it just matches 5 continuous alphanumeric characters, e.g. `"developers".scan(/\w{5}/)` returns `["devel", "opers"]`.

Comment: You're completely right, I forgot to add them! I'm editing my answer accordingly. Thanks @Stefan